# using ioctl to fill a winsize struct when piping to stdin

Tags: c, pipe, tty, ioctl

I'm trying to retrieve the width of the terminal using `ioctl()`, but it doesn't work when piping or redirecting to stdin.

I've managed to circumvent the issue by parsing the result of `tput cols`, but it feels dirty to use an external command. Also, I assume this makes it less portable as Windows doesn't use a bourne-compatible shell?

***main.c***

```c
// tput method
char res[10];

FILE cmd = popen("tput cols", "r");
fgets(res, 10 - 1, cmd);
pclose(cmd);

unsigned short term_cols = atoi(res);
printf("Term width (tput): %d\n", term_cols);

// ioctl method
struct winsize ws;
if (ioctl(STDIN_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &ws) == 0)
{
  printf("Term width (ioctl): %d\n", ws.ws_col);
}
else
{
  printf("Failed to retrieve term width from ioctl()");
}
```

***output***

> ```
> $ bin/main  
> Term width (tput): 84  
> Term width (ioctl): 84
> ```
>
> ```
> $ echo "test" | bin/main  
> Term width (tput): 84  
> Failed to retrieve term width from ioctl()
> ```

I've tried to `fflush(stdin);` at the start of my code but it doesn't make any difference. Is this just a limitation of `ioctl()` or is there a way around it?

Comment: You're not checking if `ioctl(STDIN_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &ws);` actually works.

Comment: You're right. With a pipe on stdin, its return value is `-1`. I'll edit my post, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably printing the value of an uninitialized variable. Your code doesn't check whether `ioctl` succeeds and if it fails, it leaves `ws` untouched.

Fix:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

...
if (ioctl(STDIN_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &ws) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "can't get the window size of stdin: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

When you pipe something into your program, stdin doesn't refer to a terminal but a pipe. Pipes don't have a window size. That's why `TIOCGWINSZ` fails here.

The portable solution seems to be:

```
const char *term = ctermid(NULL);
if (!term[0]) {
    fprintf(stderr, "can't get the name of my controlling terminal\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
int fd = open(term, O_RDONLY);
if (fd == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "can't open my terminal at %s: %s\n", term, strerror(errno));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if (ioctl(fd, TIOCGWINSZ, &ws) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "can't get the window size of %s: %s\n", term, strerror(errno));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
close(fd);
```

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks, fixed.